# Create/Update an Dialogeflow agent using Service Account credentials(.json file) in java

Tags: dialogflow-es, service-accounts, google-apis-explorer

I am setting up automation for Dialogflow agents and its services. To make it 100% automatic, I need to create an agent through UI using a service account credentials(rest api in background). I am able to do it through explorer but in code I'm getting response code 401, when pass AccessToken from Credentials.getAccessToken.getTokenValue().

I have explored the API docs but did not find much to create an agent through Service account credentials. Is there any way possible or I need to give more permissions to it.

```
  GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("..json"));
    if (credentials.createScopedRequired()) {
                credentials = credentials.createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow"));
        }
    }
    // and use it here
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/projectName/agent").openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue());
```